# return first two element and last two element from the list

Tags: prolog

can someone help me with this, Prolog language
find the first two-element and the last two elements from the list

the answer should be like this.

```
?- my_list([a,b, [c,[h], d], [] ,e, h], Q).
Q = [a,b,e,h]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is:

```
my_list([X1,X2|Xs], [X1,X2,X3,X4]) :- reverse(Xs, [X4,X3|_]).
```

**How does it work?**

- To get the first two elements of the list (`X1` and `X2`), you only need to use unification:

```
?- [a,b, [c,[h], d], [] ,e, h] = [X1,X2|Xs].
X1 = a,
X2 = b,
Xs = [[c, [h], d], [], e, h].
```

- To get the last two elements (`X3` and `X4`), you can use [`reverse/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reverse/2) and unification:

```
?- [a,b, [c,[h], d], [] ,e, h] = [X1,X2|Xs], reverse(Xs, [X4,X3|_]).
X1 = a,
X2 = b,
Xs = [[c, [h], d], [], e, h],
X4 = h,
X3 = e.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list(List, Result) :-
    Result = [A,B,Y,Z],
    append([A,B],  Tail, List),
    append(    _, [Y,Z], Tail).
```

Tells Prolog to seek an answer where Result must be a list of four elements, and the first two must fit a pattern of being at the front of the List leaving a remainder in Tail, and the second two must fit the pattern of being at the end of the remainder, leaving the middle of the list which we discard into `_` because we don't care about it.

You could instead use `nth1/3` to pick out the list elements by their indices; `nth1(2, List, Elem)` getting the second element. The last index coming from `length(List, Len)` and calculating the last-but-one index with math.

Or you could use pattern matching to build predicates that match the first two items in a list `[A,B|Tail]` and a list of two items `[Y,Z]` and uses recursion to trim down the Tail until it only has two elements. Then combine both those into my_list.

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog folklore there is [append](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2)/2, that allows a simple solution:

```
my_list(List,[A,B,Y,Z]) :-
  append([[A,B],_,[Y,Z]],List).
```